# How to vary $a$ and $b$ for the graph of $y=a\sin(bx)$ to keep $s_1=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2b}}\sqrt{1+a^{2}b^{2}\cos^{2}\left(bx\right)}dx$ constant

Tags: calculus

If $s_1$ has some value and one increases $b$ by some amount, one has to increase $a$ by some amount as well in order to return the value of $s_1$ to its original value.

My guess is that there would exist a non-unique pair of functions $f$ and $g$ such that if $a=f(t)$ and $b=g(t)$ then as you vary $t$, $a$ and $b$ change in precisely the right way so as to conserve the value of $s_1$. There would be infinitely many different pairs of functions you can choose, due to the fact that you can make the deformation of $y=a\sin(bx)$ happen as quickly or as slowly (with respect to $t$) as you want to

My first idea was to parametrize the sinusoid by arc length, but one does encounter an elliptic integral of the second kind in trying to do so and I'm not at all sure how to solve for $x$ in terms of arc length.

However, I do know that $$s=h\left(x\right)=\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{1+a^{2}b^{2}\cos^{2}\left(bu\right)}du$$ implies

$$x=h^{-1}\left(s\right)=h^{-1}(\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{1+a^{2}b^{2}\cos^{2}\left(bu\right)}du)$$
which seems to me about as close you can get to an actual arc length parametrization, although I'm not fully sure of that

Answer (score 1):

*Hoping that it could give you some ideas.*

Using elliptic integrals
$$S_1=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2b}}\sqrt{1+a^{2}b^{2}\cos^{2}\left(bx\right)}\,dx=\frac 1 b \,E\left(-a^2 b^2\right)$$
For
$$S_2=\int_{0}^{u}\sqrt{1+a^{2}b^{2}\cos^{2}\left(bx\right)}\,dx=$$ Mathematica returns
$$S_2=\frac 1 b\left(2 E\left(-a^2 b^2\right) \text{IntegerPart}\left[\frac{b
   u}{\pi }\right]+\sqrt{a^2 b^2+1} E\left(\pi\, 
   \text{frac}\left(\frac{b u}{\pi }\right)|1-\frac{1}{a^2
   b^2+1}\right)\right)$$

So, if you want $S_1=S_2$, you need to find the zero of function
$$E\left(-a^2 b^2\right) \left(2 \,\text{IntegerPart}\left[\frac{b
   u}{\pi }\right]-1\right)+\sqrt{a^2 b^2+1} E\left(\pi \,
   \text{frac}\left(\frac{b u}{\pi }\right)|1-\frac{1}{a^2
   b^2+1}\right)$$